# Electric potential inside insulating shells

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I came across this problem and was very confused by the solution's approach:

> A thin spherical shell with radius $R_1 = 4\,\text{cm}$ is concentric with a larger thin spherical shell with radius $R_2  = 8\,\text{cm}$.  Both  shells  are  made  of  insulating  material.  The  smaller  shell  has  charge  $q_1  =  +6\,\text{nC}$ distributed uniformly over its surface, and the larger shell has charge $q_2 = -9\,\text{nC}$ distributed uniformly over its surface. Take the electric potential to be zero at an infinite distance from both shells. What is the electric potential due to the two shells at the following distance from their common center: (i) $r = 0$; (ii) $r = 5.00\,\text{cm}$; (iii) r = $9.00\,\text{cm}$?

The solution indicated that the potential at any point inside the two shells is simply a scalar sum of the potential due to each shell. For instance, at $r = 0$, the potential would be $\frac{kQ}{R_1} + \frac{kQ}{R_2}$. Where I am confused is why this reasoning applies to **insulated** shells.

I know that for a conducting sphere of radius $R$, the potential inside the sphere is constant and equal to $V = \frac{kQ}{R}$, which is its potential at the surface, and this is due to the fact that $$E = 0 inside a conductor. However, the $E$ field would not be zero inside an insulating shell (except for at the very center?) and the potential inside should not be equal to the potential at the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation describing the electrostatic potential in the presence of charges is the Poisson equation, $\nabla^2 V = - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$. This is a linear equation, and therefore the principle of superposition holds; if $V_1$ is the potential due to charge distribution $\rho_1$, and $V_2$ is the potential due to charge distribution $\rho_2$ then the potential due to a total charge distribution $\rho = \rho_1 + \rho_2$ would simply be $V = V_1 + V_2$. This is why it is fine to consider the two shells separately, and then add the two resulting potentials in the final expression.

With this understanding, we now need to understand why the potential inside a uniformly charged spherical shell with total charge $q$ and radius $R$ is $V = \frac{kq}{R}$, where $k = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon}$ in SI units.
You are right that this is the result that would hold for a conductor, because inside a conductor the electric field is zero. However, this is *also* true for a uniformly charged spherical shell! That is, inside the shell the electric field vanishes everywhere.
This can most easily be shown by using Gauss' law inside the shell and using the fact that the spherical symmetry of the problem restricts the direction of the electric field vector.

In fact, if you replace the insulating shell by a conducting sphere, the potential would be completely unchanged. With a conductor, we expect the charges to re-distribute and exactly cancel the electric field inside the sphere. So how can the free charges re-distribute to achieve this? In fact, they will distribute uniformly on the surface of the sphere, and thus yield a charge distribution identical to the one you would have with a thin insulating shell.

Note that the fact that the vanishing of the electric field inside a perfect conductor always holds, regardless of the shape of the perfect conductor. That would not be the case in this problem, where the field only vanishes because of the spherical symmetry.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Just out of curiosity, if the insulating shell were to have a thickness, say with an inner radius of R1 = 4cm and outer radius R2 = 6cm, then is it still true that E = 0 for r < 4cm? In this case the charges are not distributed over a "surface" but over a "volume," so does the conductor analogy still work?

Comment: Yep, it does! One way to see this is by imagining the thick shell as composed of an infinite sum of infinitesimally thin shells. Each of these thin shells would have zero field inside, and therefore by the superposition principle, so would the entire sum of them.